# SetText not working when Changing tabs

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentstatepageradapter, pagerslidingtabstrip

I have a SlidingTabLayout and I'm attempting to change a settext every time a different page (Fragment) is selected.

I am attempting to do this through the fragments themselves. I have 3 total, and i'm doing so by calling `getActivity()` in the `onCreateView`

The application does not crash, but this causes the tabs to display the incorrect tab name on each tab. They are out of order and can display the name twice depending on the order clicked.

I'm not sure what I am doing wrong. Here's my current code:

Tab 1-3:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    TextView textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pageName);
    textView.setText("Tab X");

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment,container,false);

}
```

I can display more code if requested. All help is appreciated.

Comment: You must inflate the layout before accessing any UI elements in that layout. `inflater.inflate()` function should go first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open your SlidingTabLayout.java, and add this line at the beginning of the class:

```
private ArrayList<TextView> mTextView = new ArrayList<>();
```

Add this line below something like `tabTitleView.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(i));`:

```
mTextView.add(tabTitleView);
```

Finally, add this method:

```
public void changeTitle(int position) {
    final PagerAdapter adapter = mViewPager.getAdapter();
    TextView tv = mTextView.get(position);
    if (tv != null) {
        tv.setText(adapter.getPageTitle(position));
    }
}
```

Now you can call `changeTitle(0)` to change the title text for tab 0.

Comment: Where do I call `changeTitle(0)`?

Comment: Anywhere you can reference your SlidingTab. For example, `slidingTabs = (SlidingTabLayout) findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs); slidingTabs.changeTitle(0);` will change the text for tab 0.

Comment: I tried to call it inside of the Fragment's tab like this `SlidingTabLayout tabs = (SlidingTabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tabs); tabs.changetitle(0)` inside my first tab, but it gave me a nullpointerexception when I tried to call `tabs.changeTitle(0)`?

Comment: Nevermind. There was an error with the compiler. Resetting did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Tutorial and Source code is available  [here](https://github.com/astuetz/PagerSlidingTabStrip/pull/62/files?short_path=04c6e90)
and [here](http://manishkpr.webheavens.com/android-sliding-tabs-example/).

In order to change the Tab Name while swiping tabs you need to check what is the current tab say in a fragment you can check the if the Fragment's onResume method is called, Now in onResume you need to update the Text of your current Tab.

You have not given reference to your **TextView** while initializing

Do like this

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment,container,false);
        TextView textView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pageName);
        textView.setText("Tab X");

        return view ;

    }
```

Comment: It gave me a nullpointerexception on the line for "textview.setText("Tab X");" line.

Comment: @SolomonPowell make sure you have id 'pageName' in your layout discover_fragment.xml

Comment: The `pageName` id is inside a layout that contains the `discover_fragment.xml` fragment. Is there something I should change?

Answer (score 0):

> The application does not crash, but this causes the tabs to display
>   the incorrect tab name on each tab.

Call `findViewById` using `getActivity()` means accessing View from Activity layout in which current Fragment is added.

If `TextView` is inside Fragment layout then use `getView()` or `View` object which is return from `onCreateView` to access views from layout:

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,ViewGroup container, 
                                                      Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.discover_fragment,container,false);
        TextView txtView = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.pageName);
        txtView.setText("Tab X");
        return view;
    }
```

**OR**

If want to access view from Activity then make sure calling `setContentView` by passing layout id before adding Fragment to Activity:

```
TextView textView = (TextView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.pageName);
```

Comment: It gave me a nullpointerexception on the line for "textview.setText("Tab X");" line.

Comment: @SolomonPowell: in which layout you have `TextView` which `pageName` id?

Comment: You mean which layout is my textview in? The `pagename` textview is located inside my `mainactivity.xml` layout. The 3 Tabs are fragments that are displayed inside the mainactivity.